# Linear Regression with Gradient Descent, Octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

So I am trying to solve the first programming exercise from Andrew Ng's ML Coursera course. I have a little bit of trouble implementing linear gradient descent in octave. The code below shows what I am trying to implement, per the equation posted in the picture, but I am getting a different value from the expected value. I'm not sure what I am missing, I'm hoping someone can parse through this.

```
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

theta0 = theta(1);
theta1 = theta(2);

temp0 = 0;
temp1 = 0;
errFunc = 0;

for iter = 1:num_iters

    h = X * theta;
    errFunc = h - y;
    
    temp0 = temp0 + (alpha/m).*sum(errFunc'*X(:, 1));
    temp1 = temp1 + (alpha/m).*sum(errFunc'*X(:, 2));

    theta0 = theta0 - temp0;
    theta1 = theta1 - temp1;

    theta = [theta0; theta1];


    % ============================================================

    % Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2PCv.png)
My expected results are [ -3.6303; 1.1664], but I am getting [-1.361798; 0.931592]. This is the equation I am working with. [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP9vP.png)

Comment: I don't think `temp` variables should be there.

Comment: What do you mean, they should not be defined outside the loop?

Comment: You code is only equivalent to the formula you've linked if  `temp0,1` are equal to zero at the start of iteration. Either move `temp0 = 0;` inside the `for` loop or get rid of them altogether.

Comment: Oh, thanks a ton. I fixed it.